# C# - Clean way for reading data from DataSet created from XML

Tags: c#, xml, dataset

I've got an app with config.xml file added for user settings.

I am reading it simply by:

```
 DataSet config = new DataSet();
 config.ReadXml(configPath);
```

Parameters in config.xml are in columns grouped under some tables:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<UserSetup>
  <TableA>
    <revBegin>value1</revBegin>
    <revEnd>value2</revEnd>
    ...
  </TableA>
  ...
</UserSetup>
```

What I'm looking for is a clean way to read from DataSet config, without memorizing table or column names.

In my current implementation I achieved that by following class:

```
public static class MyTables
{
    public static class TableA
    {
        public const String name = "TableA";
        public const String revBegin = "revBegin";
        public const String revEnd = "revEnd";
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

And I read values like this:

```
String revEnd = config.Tables[MyTables.TableA.name].Rows[0][MyTables.TableA.revEnd].ToString();
```

But I somehow fill that it is quite easy problem solved in quite complicated - not to say nasty - way.

Do you have any idea how can I make things simpler or cleaner?

P.S. At some point I tried reducing `config.Tables[MyTables.TableA.name]` part to `config.Tables[MyTables.TableA]` but - how I see it - it would require adding `Index[object]` to sealed class `DataTableCollection` and overriding `ToString()` method in my static class - both impossible. Am I right?

Comment: I usually create a sample DataSet and then save using             config.WriteXml("filename", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);  The standard DataSet has root tag as the DataSet name, next level tag as Table names, 3rd level tags are column names followed by row data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you absolutely have to use a DataSet to read the XML, you can achieve the same results using XML serialization. Annotate your classes with the below.

```
        [XmlRoot]
        [Serializable]
        public class UserSetUp
        {
            [XmlElement]
            public TableA TableA { get; set; }
        }

        [Serializable]
        public class TableA
        {
            [XmlElement]
            public string revBegin { get; set; }

            [XmlElement]
            public string revEnd { get; set; }
        }
```

Assuming your config in on C:\ for this example.

```
    var configStream = File.OpenRead(@"C:\Config.xml");
    var reader = new StreamReader(configStream);
    var xmlString = reader.ReadToEnd();
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(UserSetUp));
    var stringReader = new StringReader(xmlString);

    var userSetup = (UserSetUp)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
```

I've tested it with the below XML and it works ok.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?>
<UserSetUp>
  <TableA>
    <revBegin>1</revBegin>
    <revEnd>2</revEnd>
  </TableA>
</UserSetUp>
```

Hope that helps you on your way.

Comment: I had to focus on something else and I didn't have time to check your solution earlier but It is exactly what I needed. In fact there is one more think I need to resolve in this approach: There is one section where user can add as many column as she/he wants and I want to foreach on them, but this is separate problem. Thank you a lot.